# How we change the date and time of database?

Tags: php, database

In database default time and date formate is YYYY,MM,DD HH MM SS.
HOW to I convert like this DD MM YYY HH MM SS ?

Comment: Cf. http://php.net/operators for a list of valid comparison operators. and `NOW()` is SQL, and hence does not work in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see here [PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) you'll see that `== <3` does not exist.

If you data is 1,2,3,4,5 then

```
$data['LogCount'] <3 // your alert will be shown if $data['LogCount'] is 1, 2 

$data['LogCount'] == 3 // your alert will be shown if $data['LogCount'] is 3 

$data['LogCount'] <= 3 // your alert will be shown if $data['LogCount'] is 1, 2, 3 
$data['LogCount'] > 3 // your alert will be shown if $data['LogCount'] is 4, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

First Problem I saw in your code is

```
if($data['LogCount'] == <3) $msg = "you are blocked ";
```

This will result to compile error because comparator is wrong

Change it to something like this

```
if($data['LogCount'] >= 3) 
$msg = "you are blocked ";
```

This will show alert when the user attempted to logged in for 3rd time 
Remove the = to show the alert at 4th time

Second  the part

```
if($data['LogCount'] >NOW());
```

Will not work SQL is different from PHP

Tip : 
When working with Log in attempt. I usually log the last time the user logged in and the number of attempts. Then I have a separate Cron jobs to refresh the value once the cooldown time has been met to reactive the user again.